# MergedDictionaries outside the primary project

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a solution with 2 projects.  First is the primary application, the second has controls in it.  In the Generic.xaml, in a Silverlight project, one would do

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyLibNamespace;component/Themes/SomeFolder/MyControl.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

This doesn't seem to work in a Windows Store application class library.  ReSharper wants the filepath to be "/Themes/SomeFolder/MyControl.xaml" but I still get a XamlParseException: Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source'. [Line: 7 Position: 36]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "Xaml file within other class/assembly" in WinRT. In other words: "EmbeddedResource" or "Resource" simply doesn't exist in a WinRT component (and yes this is a pain). This is also why \Themes\Generic.xaml is copied out into the output directory).

Answer (score 1):

See answer [here on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/winappswithcsharp/thread/bcb480d1-cb7c-4d36-ba92-9c513d95e51a)

If you have a dll named "CustomControl" with a ResourceDictionary named "Styles.xaml", the App.xaml should contain

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///CustomControls/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Different issue than what is being asked above.  that is having the app reference a XAML file within the other class

Answer (score 0):

Can reproduce the same behavior if the `ResourceDictionary` **Source** is set to a XAML that is a `UserControl`. However, if the XAML file referenced is a dedicated `ResourceDictionary`, there is no problem accessing internal styles with the **ms-appx:///** scheme, following the **ms-appx:///PROJECT_NAME/PATH_TO_XAML.xaml** pattern.

Any chance the `ResourceDictionary` can be separated from the `UserControl`, if that is the case?